# Add poi marker to a scene

Tags: android, here-api

I'd like to add markers with a text, like the embedded poi.

In version 3 of the sdk (premium edition), I used MapLabeledMarker and that worked very well. In version 4 (navigate edition) I can't find anything like that.

What is the best way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: I've been working on this today and I found a solution that consists of extending Drawable and rendering a Bitmap on a canvas with both an image and a text. It works fine but android freezes when there are a lot (1000+) of markers (this wasn't an issue with sdk v3 and MapLabeledMarker)...  I'm now considering using SVG MapImages, will it improve performance ?

Answer (score 1):

With the 4.x version of the HERE SDK, there are at least two possible solutions (for Flutter, iOS or Android):

- Consider to use `MapViewPins`: They are ordinary views (or widgets in Flutter) and they can have any content changed at runtime. However, as they are platform views, the performance is not as good as with `MapMarker` items.
- Use the `MapMarker` class. You can set and update an image on the fly. If you do this with an SVG image, it should be possible to update text labels frequently without performance degredation. When adding a (very) large number of markers at once, use `mapScene.addMapMarkers()` and pass a list of markers in a single batch call.

Comment: Can you specify how I can add MapViewPins on the map scene in android ? I can't find anything related in the doc or dev guide, the only reference to the MapViewPins is how to handle clicks on embedded markers.

Comment: I've tried the svg way and it works fine even for large amount of markers (3000+). I add them to a cluster and I can change their icons dynamically by removing them, setting the new svg and readding them (eg for night mode). This is still less performant and more difficult to use than the here sdk v3 way, but at least it works ok.

Comment: @Teriblus, just for reference, there is a whole section about MapViewPins in the dev guide: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/topics/map-items.html#add-map-view-pins